# How to filter Bitlocker Device using Powershell

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I just want to get internal Devices, which are with Bitlocker encrypted. But when I connect USB or external Hard drive, will be also read. actually, it should work just for internal devices. how could I filter ?

Here, I used this Code to get the devices

`Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption" -Classname Win32_EncryptableVolume`

Comment: Use the `DeviceID` property to correlate with `Win32_Volume` which can tell you if it's a local disk or a removable device (check `DeviceType` property)

Comment: You can filter on the `VolumeType` property, which has values of: `[0,1,2] => ['OSVolume', 'FixedDataVolume', 'PortableDataVolume']`.  I ran a quick test with an encrypted USB and it seemed to identify it correctly as 'PortableDataVolume'.